# Ubuntu 17.10 is freezing on boot

Tags: boot, 17.10, kde, plasma

I was recently using my computer to change my GTK and I noticed I have a few updates that I needed. I updated them via the Discover program and when my computer rebooted it would consistently freeze on the lock screen. I cannot access anything to help fix this issue and I have no idea what to do.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 and was using KDE Plasma

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, I purged the intel-microcode and it booted normally, drop the grub menu, choose recovery mode, then choose root shell, and do `apt purge intel-microcode` and reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! May I ask how you were able to figure out that that package was the one causing the problem?

Comment: it happens on 3.20180312.0~ubuntu17.10.1 version. I downgraded to 3.20170707.1 and computer works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

PC freeezes with high CPU (fan to max). You may have a little warning about errors about error on some CPU, seen only on console.
Freeze can occurs within a few minutes.
On my PC, it even make the next start (powercycle) behave strange: I had to powerdown, wait a few, then power back.
**Removing intel-microcode makes the trick !**